# Remove bank holidays from X Axis by amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amstock

I have data by date like this there is no `2017/07/17`,`2017/07/16`,`2017/07/15`
because they are bank holidays.

```
chartData = new Array();
        chartData[0] = new Array();
        chartData[0].closePrice = 1207;     
        chartData[0].date =  new Date("2017/07/12");
        chartData[1] = new Array();
        chartData[1].closePrice = 1227;     
        chartData[1].date =  new Date("2017/07/13");
        chartData[2] = new Array();
        chartData[2].closePrice = 1216;     
        chartData[2].date =  new Date("2017/07/14");
        chartData[3] = new Array();
        chartData[3].closePrice = 1234;     
        chartData[3].date =  new Date("2017/07/18");
```

I use this chartData as dataProvider for making graph.

```
var dataSet = new AmCharts.DataSet();
dataSet.dataProvider = chartData;
dataSet.categoryField = "date";

chart.dataSets = [dataSet];


var stockPanel = new AmCharts.StockPanel();
stockPanel.title = "Stock Main";
stockPanel.id = "stockPanel";
stockPanel.showCategoryAxis = false;
stockPanel.recalculateToPercents = "never";

var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
valueAxis.dashLength = 5;
stockPanel.addValueAxis(valueAxis);
stockPanel.categoryAxis.dashLength = 5;
stockPanel.categoryAxis.equalSpacing = true; // it doesn't work ....

var graph = new AmCharts.StockGraph();
graph.type = "line";
graph.valueField = "closePrice";
stockPanel.addStockGraph(graph);
```

however `2017/07/15`,`2017/07/16` `2017/07/16` are drawn on X axis , even there are no data.

Even `.equalSpacing` looks in vain.

How can I remove this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `equalSpacing` in the [`categoryAxesSettings`](https://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/CategoryAxesSettings#equalSpacing) property in the stock chart for it to work.

```
//object-based setup
chart.categoryAxesSettings = new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
chart.categoryAxesSettings.equalSpacing = true;
//makeChart version
AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  // ...
  "categoryAxesSettings": {
    "equalSpacing": true
  },
  // ...
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0rw0p6qd/1/)

Comment: THank you very much, I need to make `Amcharts.CategoryAxesSettings`.